# Calculate distinct values per day that resets each month (Big Query)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, distinct, distinct-values

If I have table like this that contains unique id of a store and the date when they make an order

| store_id | order_date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01-Jun-21 |
| A | 02-Jun-21 |
| B | 02-Jun-21 |
| C | 02-Jun-21 |
| A | 03-Jun-21 |
| A | 04-Jun-21 |
| D | 04-Jun-21 |
| A | 01-Jul-21 |
| B | 01-Jul-21 |

I need to aggregate it by day, but each day should only consist of store_id that never appeared before and it resets each month.

The end result should be like this:

| order_date | count store |
| --- | --- |
| 01-Jun-21 | 1 |
| 02-Jun-21 | 2 |
| 03-Jun-21 | 0 |
| 04-Jun-21 | 1 |
| 01-Jul-21 | 2 |

- At 1 Jun, only store A make order so it's 1
- At 2 Jun, store A, B, C make order, but because store A has make order before, it will be excluded
- At Jun 3, should be 0, because only order come from store A that has make order before
- At Jul 1, it resets, so store A and B are counted again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count "unique" stores cumulatively within a month, I would recommend using `row_number()` to determine the first time a store appears:

```
select order_date, countif(seqnum = 1)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by store_id, date_trunc(order_date, month)
                                order by order_date
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by order_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a correlated subquery to only retain the first entry for each month:

```
Select order_date, count(*)
From table a
Where order_date = (Select min(x.order_date) from table x
                    Where a.store_id=x.store_id
                      And Timestamp_Trunc(x.order_date,Month) = Timestamp_Trunc(a.order_date,Month)
                    )
Group by order_date
Order By order_date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Just to clarify, in the statement where  order_date = (select...)

Do you mean self joining table a?

Comment: @KaraiKare . . . Your question explicitly includes June 3rd with a `0` count.  And this does not.  I don't think it correctly answers the question you asked.

Comment: A correlated subquery is not REALLY like a self-join, but you could also solve it that way by inner joining table a to a summary query retaining the first date each company each month.

Answer (score 1):

A third, compact alternative is to nest two queries together:

```
Select EarlyOrder as Order_Date, Count(*) as Count_Store
From (Select Store_ID, Min(Order_Date) as EarlyOrder
      From table
      Group By Store_ID, Date_Trunc(Order_Date, month)
     )
Group By EarlyOrder
Order By EarlyOrder
```